# Laravel 5.1 php artisan route:list をすると Session store not set on request

Tags: php, laravel-5

php artisan route:list をすると、

```
[RuntimeException] Session store not set on request.
```

になってしまい、ルート一覧が見れないです。ご存知のかたのアドバイスなど頂ければと思います。

routes.php

```
Route::get('/', 'UserController@showProfile');
```

のコントローラアクション形式だと問題が発生し、

```
Route::get('/', function(){
    return 'Hello World';
});
```

のクロージャ形式は問題ありません。

エラーが発生しない時の結果が以下です。

```
+--------+----------+------------------------------+----------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI                          | Name                 | Action                                                        | Middleware |
+--------+----------+------------------------------+----------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /                            |                      | Closure                                                       |            |
|        | GET|HEAD | _debugbar/assets/javascript  | debugbar.assets.js   | Barryvdh\Debugbar\Controllers\AssetController@js              |            |
|        | GET|HEAD | _debugbar/assets/stylesheets | debugbar.assets.css  | Barryvdh\Debugbar\Controllers\AssetController@css             |            |
|        | GET|HEAD | _debugbar/clockwork/{id}     | debugbar.clockwork   | Barryvdh\Debugbar\Controllers\OpenHandlerController@clockwork |            |
|        | GET|HEAD | _debugbar/open               | debugbar.openhandler | Barryvdh\Debugbar\Controllers\OpenHandlerController@handle    |            |
+--------+----------+------------------------------+----------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
```

エラーの原因がわからず、どのようにすればルート一覧が見れるようになるのかご教示いただければ幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

私もちょうど`Laravel 5.1`の環境で開発を始めたところなので、確認を取ってみました。

結果的には、クロージャ形式でもコントローラアクション形式でも問題なく表示が行われています。ですので、指定形式の問題ではないと考えられます。以下の手順で問題を探ってみてはいかがでしょうか。

1. ご指定の`UserController`ではなく、別なコントローラを作成して、表示できるかどうか確認してみてください。ここで表示されれば、`UserController`周りに問題がありそうです。
2. 表示が失敗した場合、これは全体設定の問題である可能性があります。セッション周りの設定などを確認してみてはいかがでしょうか。
3. 場合によっては、別にプロジェクトを作成し、簡単なコントローラとビューを配置し、それをコントローラアクション形式で呼び出す設定をして、コマンドの表示を確認してください。
4. それがうまくいくようなら、そのプロジェクトに`UserController`をコピーして動作を確認することも有効と思います。

直接の回答とはなりませんが、お役に立てば幸いです。